# How do I compare two different values of the same field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables in MySQL representing Suppliers that sell Parts through a Catalog:

Suppliers(sid, sname, address), sid being the primary key (an integer)

Parts(pid, pname, color), pid being the primary key (an integer)

Catalog(sid, pid, cost), sid and pid being the primary key

**Now I am trying to select the names of the Suppliers that are supplying two Parts of different colors.** So far I have only managed to figure out how to select the sid's of suppliers that are selling more than one part with the following code:

```
SELECT sid
FROM catalog
GROUP BY sid
HAVING COUNT(sid) > 1;
```

I am however at a loss with how to select two parts from a specific supplier and compare their color values. It seems like I need some kind of subquery but I am not sure exactly how to go about it. Any guidance in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: compare their color values how? red screwdrivers and yellow hammers?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the part actually is, all I care about is if the color fields are the same like 'red', 'yellow' etc I just don't know how to compare the same field of two different Part entries.

Comment: yeah, but compare for what purpose? sql doesn't generally let you compare fields in different records without more advanced queries, like self-joins.

Comment: This is for a 4th year University assignment so practical application of this is probably minimal. The question reads: "Find the name for each supplier who has supplied two parts with different color." And the three tables have been given as I described above.

Comment: now that's useful information.

Comment: @MarcB Actually it does, but you don't need a `HAVING` clause to do it, unless you expect there to be multiple entries with the same color, which for a part is possible. It can also be filtered down with the `DISTINCT` keyword to preclude those duplicate rows. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, you could use a self join where you declare that the PID must be the same but the Color must be different, similar to the below:

```
SELECT s.sid, s.sname, p.*
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.pid, a.color, b.color
    FROM parts AS a
    JOIN parts AS b ON b.pid == a.pid AND b.color <> a.color
) AS p
JOIN catalog AS c ON c.pid == p.pid
JOIN suppliers AS s ON s.sid == c.sid
```

No need for a having clause, even if you want to use a GROUP BY to accomplish the same thing:

```
SELECT s.sid, s.sname, p.*
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT pid, color
    FROM parts
    GROUP BY pid, color
) AS p
JOIN catalog AS c ON c.pid == p.pid
JOIN suppliers AS s ON s.sid == c.sid
```

In either case, the surrounding query and joins should work to provide an accurate list for you to work with.

I Hope this helps.

-C§

Comment: I needed to make a few minor alterations but this is exactly what I needed to figure out how to approach the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2023740 You're quite welcome. That's what we're all here for. =D